# Select Product Attribute Options when programmatically creating a simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, category-products

I have created products programmatically by following [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/) post. I have assigned the required attribute set.

`$sproduct->setAttributeSetId(attribute_set_id)`

But my requirement is to select the relevant attribute options from the attributes in the attribute set.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's "relevant attribute options"? please give an example.

Comment: I've got an attribute called "type of user" where there are two attribute options "Students" and "Other". I want to select one option programmatically. I'm creating these simple products to attach them to a configurable product as "Associated Products"

Comment: `$product->setTypeOfUser(id of the option here)`